# Email a daily calendar summary to a Outlook Group

Tags: power-automate

I have a service department that needs to keep everyone informed on what everyone is doing on a daily basis. I was thinking that an Outlook Group or Sharepoint Team Site would give the department the ability to keep a shared calendar and Power Automate could email daily upcoming event summaries. I have attempted to use these suites with Automate to sync member calendars, or creating a shared calendar, but PA doesn't have access to Outlook Group calendars, and Sharepoint no longer has an integrated calendar (one that isn't an app).

Does anyone have an idea how to integrate one of these group suites (or even a Teams calendar) to accomplish this?

Comment: You can use a Power Automate flow to call Graph api which will fetch all calender details and then post it to teams.